# Acknowledgements on a Masters thesis

Tags: thesis, masters, acknowledgement

Is it wrong or looked upon to acknowledge God on Master's thesis paper?

Comment: Maybe not if you field is Theology, but otherwise it will look weird, might even rub someone the wrong way.